# How to disable home button wake up on HTC 10 with Android 7.0

Tags: htc, 7.0-nougat

I recently got the 7.0 update on my HTC 10, and now my home button wakes my phone up. I had this setting disabled under the fingerprint section in the settings, however, the phone is not respecting that setting any longer. I tried toggling it on and off, but it changes nothing.

How can I disable this button from waking my phone up on Android 7.0?

Comment: Did you resolve it? I have same problem when update to android 7.0

Comment: Anh, no, I did not solve it. I did a factory reset, and the issue remained. I upgraded to Lineage 7.1.1 and the issue persists.